# dequeueBuffer failed, error = -110; switching to fallback

Tags: android, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I am trying to draw on `SurfaceView` using a `Thread` but got following warning:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: dequeueBuffer failed, error = -110; switching to fallback
```

When this warning is being shown, the surfaceview becomes black colored.